# Valid values for LC_CTYPE?

Tags: linux, osx, locale, i18n

I have found a number of questions on various forums where Mac users complain about `locale` errors when they log in to Linux systems over SSH which complain that the `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` setting is incorrect.

In some more detail, the shell on MacOS seems to set this value, and then (if you have the option enabled in Terminal, or etc) your local `LC_*` variables get exported to the remote system when you SSH in.

Linux insists that `LC_CTYPE` needs to be set to a valid locale (sometimes you can fix this with `localegen` as admin on the Linux system) but `UTF-8` is not a locale in the first place.

My *primary* question is, is this a bug in MacOS? Or is Linux wrong in insisting that the variable needs to be set to a fully specified locale name?

Secondarily, in order to be able to argue which one is correct and why, where is this specified?

Tertiarily, is there something these Mac users (myself included) could or should do differently?

The obvious workaround is to put something like

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

in your `.bash_profile`, but this obviously only solves it for your personal account, and hardcodes a value which may or may not agree with your other `locale` settings.

Comment: For instance [this](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/5478).  [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) doesn't happen to address adequately what happens when different systems can't agree on the valid locale settings, though you're certain to get opinion in lieu of fact here.

Comment: [Section 7 of POSIX 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html) does discuss this at some length (you linked to section 8).

Comment: This seems relevant too: https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-6565 -- here is the corresponding commit: https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/commit/bec6614bdd86baa2f8e86644f6230815df96560e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic question is

> My primary question is, is this a bug in MacOS? Or is Linux wrong in insisting that the variable needs to be set to a fully specified locale name?

and the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) page for environment variables shows the reason why others view the macOS configuration as incorrect:

> [XSI] ***If*** the locale value has the form:
>
> ```
> language[_territory][.codeset]
> ```
>
> it refers to an implementation-provided locale, where settings of language, territory, and codeset are ***implementation-defined***.
>
> **`LC_COLLATE`**, **`LC_CTYPE`**, **`LC_MESSAGES`**, **`LC_MONETARY`**, **`LC_NUMERIC`**, and **`LC_TIME`** are defined to accept an additional field @ modifier, which allows the user to select a specific instance of localization data within a single category (for example, for selecting the dictionary as opposed to the character ordering of data). The syntax for these environment variables is thus defined as:
>
> ```
> [language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier]]
> ```
>
> For example, if a user wanted to interact with the system in French, but required to sort German text files, LANG and LC_COLLATE could be defined as:
>
> ```
> LANG=Fr_FR
> LC_COLLATE=De_DE
> ```
>
> This could be extended to select dictionary collation (say) by use of the @ modifier field; for example:
>
> ```
> LC_COLLATE=De_DE@dict
> ```
>
> **An implementation may support other formats.**
>
> **If the locale value is not recognized by the implementation, the behavior is unspecified.**

That is, they assume that POSIX prescribes a syntax for the locale settings.
An unwary reader would assume that POSIX defines the permissible forms for the environment variables so that the ***codeset*** value is optional, and not act as a replacement for the ***language***.  But that last "may" opens up a can of worms, in effect blessing this difference in interpretation.  Apple can do whatever it wants, if it wants to provide valid locales which don't follow that pattern exactly.

@tripleee suggested that the page on [Locale](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html) gives better information, but that is almost entirely a discussion of the locale definitions rather than providing guidance for *interoperability* (i.e., POSIX's ostensible goal).

Neither page addresses differences in the available locale settings (such as ".utf8" versus ".UTF-8").  Those are implementation-dependent, as noted on the POSIX page.  That leaves users with the sole solution being to determine for themselves what locale settings are supported on the local and remote systems, and (ssh behavior here) determine how to set those on the remote system "compatibly".

Answer (score 7):

I didn't get into the details of who's "right or wrong" - but was equally annoyed by the issue. Some solutions to this:

- Server-side:

  - change/disable `AcceptEnv LC_*` in `/etc/ssh/sshd`

    - cons: it sets them to the system-default
  - edit `.profile`

    - cons: single user
  - edit `/etc/bash*` or `/etc/profile`

    - cons: may be reversed in updates
- Client-side:

  - `alias ssh="LC_CTYPE=\"${LANG}\" ssh"` in `.bashrc`/`.profile`/whereEver

    - cons: single user
  - same as server-side in `.bashrc`/`.profile`...
  - change/add settings in Terminal

    - con: entire session, be it local or remote

So, in the end I ended up creating `mac-locale-fix.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` on the server (raspian in my case) with this line in it:

```
[ "A${LC_CTYPE}" == "AUTF-8" ] && export LC_CTYPE="${LANG}"
```

Hope this helps others...

Comment: Thanks, I'm upvoting this but still looking for authoritative answers.